# Lectures are way ahead of the planned schedule for the course. What should be done?

Tags: lecturer, lecture-teaching-method, course-design

In my university, we submit a lecture plan at the academic semester starts. The lecture plan is a kind of semi-official documentation on the schedule of lectures or topics (Ref: [Planning a course: lecture-by-lecture or topic-by-topic?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83408/planning-a-course-lecture-by-lecture-or-topic-by-topic)). The lecture plan looks like the following that also includes the plan for quizzes, tests, projects.

```
--------------------------------------------
Week    Topic      Subtopics     Expectation
--------------------------------------------
W01     Topic1     St1, St2      To achieve.
W02     Topic1     St3, St4      ---
...some weeks of such lecturing...
Quiz1 ...
W07     Topic7     St1, St2      ---
W08     Topic8     St1, St2      ---
...and some more...
Mid-way Test
...Again lecturing...
Project
Final test
---------------------------------------------
```

Now I am in a problem. The mid-way test has been scheduled in next 3 weeks. But, I have completed all the stuff required for the mid-way test. I don't have any more things to lecture and I don't want to.

Should I complete the course well before time? But, again my dean might not be happy with this.

Or, what should one lecturer do in such a scenario?

Suggestion with some experiences would be really appreciated.

P.S. This is undergrad course if at all it matters.

Comment: What you should do is not get so massively ahead. Even if you get one lecture ahead, you need to slow down and add extra material: more background, more examples, more explanations, etc.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Pressing brakes from the beginning looks like the only solution in such a case. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, when a course is assigned a certain number of credit hours, that means that students (and professors) can expect a related number of contact-hours via lecture, tutorials or labs. Your students and dean will likely be upset if you cancel classes for next 3 weeks.

If you don't want to introduce new material, there are several things you could do.

- Review material or go further into depth
- Have students work on their projects
- Have students work on homework or small projects